# How do I clear up this ambiguous call to Arrays.copyof()?

Tags: java, android, aide-ide

I'm running AIDE on my Android phone, and am having trouble compiling the following bit of Java code:

`elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, elements.length * 2);`

Here `elements` is of type `int[]`. The error I'm getting from AIDE is

`Several methods are applicable to (int[], int): 'java.util.Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)' and 'java.util.Arrays.copyOf<T>(T[], int)'`

I would've expected the compiler to pick the former option, but it doesn't. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Good question because `T` can't be `int` type.

Comment: Sounds like a compiler/IDE problem, because there's really just one valid overload that could be used (the first one). Plus: Eclipse can easily compile this line and knows exactly which one to call.

Comment: It must be a compiler problem if it works in eclipse then. Still, anyone know if there a way to coax the compiler into picking one?

Comment: Just wondering - why aren't you using an `ArrayList` as that would handle the resizing for you.

Comment: Have you tried casting the first argument to int[]: `Arrays.copyOf((int[]) elements, elements.length * 2)`?

Comment: @Dave,  because ArrayList boxes each value, which has a pretty big overhead.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I've tried, but that didn't work either

Comment: Sounds like a bug for me. I just tried this IDE, static imports seems not to work either. And there not hint about which compiler is used. Iwould suggest to raise a bug or switch to another android IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler/IDE problem. However, `Arrays.copyOf` is a quite trivial function, so simply write your own version of it if the problem can't be fixed with IDE/compiler updates. Another way would be to use reflection to call it. But it comes with some runtime overhead and  also makes the code look awkward, so I suggest implementing your own version.

Here is the code:

```
public static int[] copyOf(int[] original, int newLength) {
    int[] copy = new int[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Of course, if you then get the same problem for `System.arraycopy`, then this does not work. Simply try it. If it does not work, you can place it in a helper class and use a non-buggy compiler to compile this helper class.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Not true. `Arrays.copyOf` is a normal java function that just creates a new array and invokes `System.arrayCopy`. Added its source code to the answer.

Comment: indeed, I confused it with `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: Yes it must be a compiler problem. I'll submit a bug report